# I've made new variables using 'mutate' in Tidyverse but they won't export with the original dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm using Tidyverse. I'm new to R.
I want to create some new variables based on some calculations.

My column names are subject, block and latency.

I created mean and sd using the summarise function. My table showed this.
Then I used 'mutate' to create a 95% and 5% column and these don't show on the table.

Any idea why?

I would provide the code but I can't seem to post the question with the code because no matter what I do, it doesn't like my formatting and won't allow me to post the question.

Many thanks if you can help :-)

Comment: You are printing subjSummary_s1, which is unchanged, at the end of your pipes. Just remove that last command. Instead, you might want to assign the second half to a variable name, otherwise it will only be calculated and displayed, but not be saved anywhere

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll do that.

Comment: You're a genius, it worked!!  Yay :-)  newVariable<-currentTibble%>% mutate(a = 2.5*b)